# How to prevent Firefox from restoring session on startup in KDE Plasma

Tags: firefox, linux

Firefox 118.0.2 Arch Linux on KDE Plasma 5

When I boot and open Firefox the first time, it insists of restoring the session.

How to prevent that?

I've disabled open previous windows and tabs in settings.

I've tried messing around in `about:config`

```
 browser.sessionstore.resume_session_once = false
 browser.sessionstore.max_resumed_crashes = 0
 browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash = false
 browser.sessionstore.collect_session_storage = false
 browser.sessionstore.resuming_after_os_restart = false
 browser.sessionstore.enabled = flase
 browser.sessionstore.max_tabs_undo = 0
 browser.sessionstore.max_windows_undo = 0.
 browser.sessionstore.collect_session_storage = false
 browser.sessionstore.platform_collection = false
 browser.sessionstore.restore_on_demand = false
 browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash = false 
 browser.sessionstore.upgradeBackup.maxUpgradeBackups = 0
 browser.sessionstore.platform_collection = false
 browser.sessionstore.max_serialize_back = 0
```

I've followed this [thread](https://support.mozilla.org/zu/questions/1397414).

This is telling me to close Firefox and wait until the maintenance of the data is done and then shutdown (BTW, my opinion is that it is ridiculous to close the browser and wait 30s just to delete sessions).

"The Linux version of Firefox also has an integration with the OS so if you shut down the OS without first quitting Firefox, when Firefox is instructed by the OS that it needs to close for a system shutdown, it sets a flag to restore your session at the next startup." - Where is the opt to just don't do that?

I've followed these thread: https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/1386518

This is telling me to create a customized config file named `autoconfig.cfg`. I placed it in `/usr/lib/firefox/defaults/pref/`. Did not work.

I've tried to use policies like described on [support](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson) and [templates](https://mozilla.github.io/policy-templates/). I've placed it in `/var/lib/firefox/distribution/`.

My `policy.json` file:

```
{
  "policies": {
    "Homepage": {
      "URL": "127.0.0.1",
      "Locked": false,
      "Additional": [],
      "StartPage": "homepage-locked"
    }
  }
}
```

Did not work.

I've created a script that deletes `~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*` and `/home/mad_mosel/profile.default-release/sessionstore-backups/*` on shutdown. Did not work.

Tried deleting random files and folders in `~/.mozilla/firefox/profile.default-release`. Could not identify where the session is stored.

Is there anything else that I can try?